# Do mathematicians ignore mathematical works from non-mathematicians?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list

Is it true that mathematicians ignore and do not like to take a look at or comment on any mathematical work or manuscript from a person outside the field of mathematics (meaning is not a professional mathematician or does not have any prior publications/qualifications in mathematics)?

I am asking out of personal experience, over and over again, not from one but many.

Comment: Sorry If this is not the best place, but I dont have any other place.

Comment: Here are three: Academia, Math.StackExchange, and Workplace.  I mention the last because the question phrased above generalizes to: why do professionals in an area whose job is to promote their profession not spend their time considering input from non professionals writing in that area?  Phrased this way, you might come up with the answer: "It depends; sometimes one does consider such." This is the wrong forum for your question.  Gerhard "Speaking As A Non-Professional Mathematician" Paseman, 2020.04.25.

Comment: Even if some one, say X, is not a professional mathematician, if X's work is endorsed by a  professional mathematician, in the sense X acknowledges (in a research article) a professional mathematician, then there is a chance that people would like to spend some time.. This is only based on my experience.. Everyday professional mathematicians get emails from random person asking to check their idea (I heard it from a faculty whose  area is (Algebraic) Number theory).. So, may be that spam emails is affecting a genuine question/response from some one who is not a professional mathematician..

Comment: Because, to begin with, much of mathematical work by professional mathematicians is ignored by other mathematicians, too.  It is really difficult to do something in mathematics that would be recognized by mathematicians as relevant.

Comment: Sometimes, they do, in the case of work done by physicists. But, there has to be a specific reason for a mathematician to read any particular paper. Life is short and people are busy. Lastly, quality of math work written by non-mathematicians, on average, is atrocious, so, on average, reading such work amounts to waste of time.

Comment: I finally published my paper in a mathematics journal. I asked so many mathematicians for feedback, but none gave. One mathematicians said it was correct but nothing more than that. He did not even suggest any future directions also. I kept on improving it over my own criticism and it finally got accepted in a reasonable journal. Now I am writing my second paper in continuation, but finding it strange and demotivating to think that  nobody in the world is going to read it except one or two who absolutely have to due to their profession.

Comment: A huge number of articles published in reputable mathematics journals are never cited by any other papers. This doesn't mean that they weren't read, but it indicates that no one was sufficiently interested to follow up on the contents. You can take two views. One is to get discouraged. The other (my preference) is to view doing mathematical research as something that I do for my own sake, pursuing problems that I find interesting. If perchance others find my work interesting, that's great. But if not, okay, it's still interesting to me.

Comment: "He did not even suggest any future directions also" I think expecting such suggestions is in general unreasonable. That said, congratulations on your publication!

Comment: Mathematicians spend a tremendous amount of time carefully reading and thoroughly commenting on work by people who have never published before: our PhD students.

Comment: Good illustrating example of opinion-based question (motivating [this question on meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4235/primarily-opinion-based-questions-answers)).

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju Only few have succeeded this way. You need to overcome the hidden bias that "Your work is unlikely to be impactful for them to spend time on it". How can you convince them that your work will help them as well?

Comment: This question seems to assume that the way you have been treated implies things about how mathematicians treat a wide group of people. Are you basing the claim in the title of your question solely on your own experience, or do you have other information/evidence?

Comment: I looked at your paper on arXiv (presumably, the one that was accepted for publication). It is quite far from my area of math, but looks like a solid piece of work. If it were ignored by mathematicians you sent the paper to, my guess is that this is not because you are a non-mathematician, but because they did not find it particularly interesting. They would have had the same reaction to a generic math paper posted on the arXiv. Keep working and maybe, eventually, you will find somebody interested in your work.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Or even that they did find it interesting, but had other more interesting or pressing things on their mind.  The number of papers I find interesting is much more than the number of papers I have time to read.

Comment: @NoahSnyder: Agreed.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes, probably they did not have time and energy to refocus and concentrate on my paper/topic which is not exactly related to their work. Also my experience is that say an expert in subfield $A$ would not like to give comments on something related to subfiled $B$ because they probably do not think they can give comment with same insight as they would have if it were topic $A$. So they may pass it on as it was someone else's job and not theirs. Thank you Andres Caicedo.

Comment: But they are very helpful, when I ask something about any mathematical sub problems I face, if it is generic. Infact I have thanked mathoverflow and math.SE communities in my paper. I am indebted to these communities, without which I wouldnt have arrived at right problem formulations and solutions.

Comment: @YemonChoi : Its based on my experience. I don't know if it is the general case and thats what I'd also like to know. "mathematicians treat a wide group of people" may not be correct but "mathematicians treat work from people outside math"

Comment: @JoeSilverman Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Dear Rajesh, perhaps it will comfort you to know that a mathematician may also face the same problem while trying to be taken seriously by professionals in other communities. I speak this as a professional mathematician who has been dabbling with statistics. A big, if not the biggest, problem I have is to understand what makes a problem "interesting" to people in that community. It helps to learn their language, and sometimes people would be interested if formulated in the right way.

Comment: I've rewritten the question in a less affirmative way (replacing "*why do they ignore*" with "*do they ignore*"), so as to make it a real question.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, [also](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358507/do-mathematicians-ignore-mathematical-works-from-non-mathematicians#comment901716_358507), the quality of math work written by mathematicians is often atrocious, at least from the point of view of writing rather than of mathematics.

Comment: This question is now unbelievably broad, and can be answered by a single counterexample: Ramanujan was taken seriously by Hardy. But the fact he was such an atypical case means this answer is useless. Here's another, more recent example that is not so outlandish: [Aubrey de Grey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aubrey_de_Grey), who a few years ago [made progress on an open problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.02385). What is really going on is mathematicians very rarely look at work that is badly presented and/or super niche and/or has a very high chance of being trivially wrong.

Comment: @LeonidPositselski : So as per your comment, there is rarely any team work in mathematics?

Answer (score 17):

In my experience, looking at work by non-professionals, they seem to totally ignore the existing literature by mathematicians.
So, why should I as a professional look at someones work, where that person has not bothered with reading themselves?

Also, not learning to typeset stuff in LaTeX is just plain lazy - it is a standard nowadays, and not difficult to learn.
A person without patience to learn LaTeX, most likely do not have the patience to solve an interesting problem.

Edit: Vixra, (*ViXra.org is an e-print archive set up as an alternative to the popular arXiv.org service owned by Cornell University.*) is a good source of 'papers' written by mainly amateurs which gives quite a clear picture why professionals do not care.

Every third submission in the Number theory section is a 7-page paper claiming to solve the Riemann Hypothesis.
Moreover, it seems that all these different people completely ignore all the other 'proofs' of RH on vixra.

Papers on vixra, I feel, are fair game to criticize, as it claims to be an alternative to arxiv. One point of putting papers on arxiv, is to get input on the preprint, and allow the scientific community to give feedback on it.

The point is, an afternoon of browsing papers on vixra will answer the question why professional mathematicians rarely care about the works of amateurs.

Comment: What does latex has anything do with this question?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, a lot.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik "any mathematical work or manuscript".

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik 
For example, from vixra: https://vixra.org/pdf/2004.0556v1.pdf (proof that there are no odd almost perfect numbers)... and more than half of the references are the authors previous work...

Comment: @WlodAA but OP has not mentioned he do not know latex?

Comment: I do not know if it is ok to give some example of a badly written file (by a student in a school?) to answer this question... maybe you are assuming OP is not aware how to write in LaTeX...

Comment: Anyway, @RajeshDachiraju is partially right, of course. It's just another fact of life. I have first-hand similar experiences. This world is nothing but CHAOS.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik that examle is from vixra. It is supposed to be an alternative to arxiv, and thus gives a good example on what 'papers' by amateurs do look like.

Comment: One may not be able to deduce a paper's validity from the non-use of LaTeX, but it's nonetheless a strong signal. See point (1) here: https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=304

Comment: @Neal of course, but a 'paper' lacking both LaTeX AND where there are no references to any paper or preprint written by a professional mathematician the last 10-20 years, is probably not something worth spending time reading.

Comment: @Per Alexandersson: *lacking both LaTeX AND where there are no references to any paper or preprint written by a professional mathematician the last 10-20 years* --- Interestingly, [this manuscript that I wrote back in 2011](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316692623_A_detailed_and_elementary_solution_to_x17_1) comes *very close* to qualifying, but I do agree with your general point. (There's a reason I was forced at the time to use MS Word, but I don't have room here to fully explain why.)